# Resuming From Notification Center

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, notifications, push-notification

I'm wondering if anyone has any experience resuming an iPhone app from notification center and if there is a way to see which notification the app was resumed from.  Let's say that there are 5 different notification and they slide to view from lock screen or tap to view from Notification Center.  Is there any way for me to see the data that was sent with that specific notification?  I'm already storing data from notifications when didReceiveRemoteNotification is called.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes..when creating a notification you can include a `NSDictionary` as its `userinfo` and in your app delegate `applicationdiDfinishLaunching`..
 you can get the notification and then that dictionary with its .`userinfo` property

like this
in your `applicationdiDfinishLaunching`

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (localNotification) {
    NSLog(@"Notification Body: %@",localNotification.alertBody);
    NSLog(@"%@", localNotification.userInfo);
}
```